# Why am I obtaining this error in this TypeScript arrow function?

Tags: typescript, arrow-functions

I am finding some difficulties writing an **arrow function** that take 2 date parameters and check if these dates objet represents the same day.

```
var result = (event.startDate, event.endDate) => { event.startDate.getFullYear() === event.endDate.getFullYear() &&
                                      event.startDate.getMonth() === event.endDate.getMonth() &&
                                      event.startDate.getDate() === event.endDate.getDate()
                                    }
```

But Visual Studio Code give me this error on the code: **;' expected.**

And compiling my code I obtain:

```
ERROR in src/app/people-list/people-list.component.ts:103:51 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

103     var result = (event.startDate, event.endDate) => { event.startDate.getFullYear() === event.endDate.getFullYear() &&
```

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix it?
Another doubt is: have I to explicetly return the result or the result return is inplicit in arrow function?

Comment: 1. The error seems to be that you miss `;` either immediately *after* the closing `}` or immediately *before*. Technically, you can have one at each place, I'm just not sure which one the compiler asks for. 2. That function will produce `undefined` all the time. Either remove `{` and `}` or add a `return`

Comment: `(event.startDate, event.endDate) => {}` this is not how you define function argument list. If you want `result` to be the result of the expression evaluation you don't need to create an arrow function `var result = event.startDate.getFullYear() === event.endDate.getFullYear()...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error about the missing semi-colon is because the body of your arrow function is in a block so each statement has to be terminated correctly.

That being said I think the missing semi-colon is not the only problem.  First the way your arrow function is defined doesn't look right.  It looks like you are defining a function but the parameter definitions look like they are the properties of an existig variable event.

If you already have the event object, not sure why you need an arrow function.

```js
    var result = event.startDate.getFullYear() === event.endDate.getFullYear() &&                                       event.startDate.getMonth() === event.endDate.getMonth() &&                                           event.startDate.getDate() === event.endDate.getDate();
```

Should end up with result being true or false.  If you really want to use an arrow function you would need somethnig like this

```js
const fn = (event: any) =>  event.startDate.getFullYear() === event.endDate.getFullYear() &&                                       event.startDate.getMonth() === event.endDate.getMonth() &&                                           event.startDate.getDate() === event.endDate.getDate();

const result = fn(event);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what are you trying to achieve here. You have two problems here:

1. The function (in this form) needs to have a return statement.
2. You don't specify input arguments like this.

   const result = (startDate : Date, endDate : Date) => {
       return startDate.getFullYear() === endDate.getFullYear() && startDate.getMonth() === endDate.getMonth() && startDate.getDate() === endDate.getDate();
   }

That is simply how arrow functions work.

Tip in the end: Since you are using TypeScript, avoid using **var**. Use **let** and **const** instead. Specifically (in this case), use **const** for function definitions like this.